# How to add a comma as a separator for multiple selection data in infopath sharepoint for eg it should come as test 1, test 2, test 3,

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, 2010, sharepoint-designer, infopath

How to add a comma as a separator for multiple selection data in info path share point for eg it should come as test 1, test 2, test 3,..

Answer (score 0):

you can add a button with a rule to set the text filed with the following formula

> eval(eval(field1, 'concat(., ",")'), "..")

Change the field1 with the multiple choice filed.

[image]

Reference:https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d62e8c9e-cd02-4588-96be-17b4a3e633d3/passing-selected-value-of-a-multipleselection-list-box-to-a-text-box-in-infopath-2013?forum=sharepointcustomization

Comment: I already have a submit button using another one will create confusion, Is there any other options of getting the multiple selection to come with a comma in sharepoint list